# Creating an edit form with partial views MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, mvc-editor-templates

I have data structure for organisation As follows:

```
public class Organisation
{
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string OrganisationCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrganisationSite> Sites { get; set; }
    public string TelNo { get; set; }
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

An address is stored as its' own entity:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string HouseNoName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Locality { get; set; }
    public string TownCity { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Za-z]{0,1} {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2}$", ErrorMessage="Postcode must be recognisable UK postal code")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
    public AddressType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Address will be used in many places thoughout an application so sounds like I need a partial view that I can reuse? In my OrganisationController I am going to make a trip to my OrganisationRepository and include the Address entity(entity framework):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 1)
    {
        var organisation = _db.Organisation.Include("Address").Single(og => og.OrganisationId == id);
        if (organisation == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(organisation);
    }
```

How do I render a partial address view in my Organisation Edit view? I have had a quick look  and seen reference to EditorTemplates, is this the approach I need to take, if so do you know of any decent tutorials as the ones I've seen appear fairly deep?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=load+partial+view+with+ajax+mvc+4&oq=load+partial+view+wit&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4967j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Forgive me if I don't +1 your fine advice Bodily........ Most helpful.

Comment: the way to load a partial view as you have requested is to use an ajax call via jquery.  my link was a google search for that with many results on how to do that.  I am sorry if you didn't find it helpful